# Run PHP Code Sniffer without CLI (in browser)

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

I want to run PHP Code Sniffer from server where I don't have SSH access. However, it's possible to upload or ask hosting provider to install PHP Code Sniffer from composer.

Is it possible to run it without CLI (from browser) after? I have ability to  upload files on server, including PHP scripts. I can't do shell_exec, etc.

Comment: I doubt it, at least not in any way for the intended use of the tool.  Since PHP Code Sniffer analyzes static code, can't you just run it on your workstation?  Why does it need to be on the server?

Comment: yes, I can, but we have lots of small clients with large codebases. We want to speedup our stuff and run script without downloading anything.

Comment: AFAIK, the "sniffer" must have access to all "local" files.